# Multi-threading State in Java with Semaphores

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a question about using Semaphores in multithreaded Java code.

```
There are three threads being fired asynchronously. One of them calls zero(), the other calls even(), and the last one calls odd(). "0102" is the correct output.


Semaphore zero = new Semaphore(1);
Semaphore odd = new Semaphore(0);
Semaphore even = new Semaphore(0);

public void zero(IntConsumer printNumber) throws InterruptedException {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            zero.acquireInterruptibly();
            printNumber.accept(0);
            if(i % 2 == 0) {
                odd.release();
            } else {
                even.release();
            }
        }
    }

    public void even(IntConsumer printNumber) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i += 2) {
            even.acquire();
            printNumber.accept(i);
            zero.release();
        }
    }

    public void odd(IntConsumer printNumber) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i += 2) {
            odd.acquire();
            printNumber.accept(i);
            zero.release();
        }
    }
```

In the code shown above, the first function that will run is function 'zero' because only that lock is able to be required. Then, the function 'odd' will be able to be called from another thread since it's lock has been released and therefore able to be acquired.

Two questions:

1) Can the same thread that acquired the 'zero' lock reenter the for loop before the lock has been released by the function 'odd'

2) How is the state of the for loop preserved after a thread has been switched out?

Edit: In understanding semaphores a bit more, I know realize that regardless of whether the fact that the thread had acquired the semaphore before, it can not run unless the number of permits available for that sempaphore is greater than 0. Therefore, until the number of permits available is greater than 0, the function will not be able to run until a release of that semaphore occurs so that the number of permits available is greater than 0. The question remains though, how is that state of the for loop preserved so that when I reenter the for loop, I do not start back at the initial 'i' value.

Comment: Different threads = different stacks.

Comment: Thank you @JohannesKuhn